# How to properly map JSON object?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ObjectMapperJSON {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException {

      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
      String jsonString = "{\"numberOFiles\":13, \"filename\":\"123.jpg\"}";

    /*  int temp = Integer.parseInt(jsonString); 
    */  ObjectMapper objectMapper = getObjectMapper();

objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

      try{
         JsonBean JsonBean = mapper.readValue(jsonString, JsonBean.class);

         System.out.println(JsonBean);

         jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(JsonBean);
         //jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(JsonBean);

         System.out.println(jsonString);
      }
      catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();}
   }
 }
```

**The outprint from this is: 
Filename [ filename: 123.jpg, numberOfFiles: 0 ]
{
  "filename" : "123.jpg",
  "numberOfFiles" : 0**

So my question is why the value of numberOfFiles is printed out as 0? Debugging shows me the value until the last syso as 13. How to properly do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your json string. 
Update `numberOFiles` to `numberOfFiles`.

Comment: My god. Thank you. Tried to solve this for an hour. You deserve your upvote.